# Is it possible to access module state in a terraform remote state file?

Tags: terraform

If a terraform script uses a module that has outputs, it's possible to access those module outputs in using the `-module` option for the `terraform output` command:

```
$ terraform output --help
Usage: terraform output [options] [NAME]

  Reads an output variable from a Terraform state file and prints
  the value.  If NAME is not specified, all outputs are printed.

Options:

  -state=path      Path to the state file to read. Defaults to
                   "terraform.tfstate".

  -no-color        If specified, output won't contain any color.

  -module=name     If specified, returns the outputs for a
                   specific module

  -json            If specified, machine readable output will be
                   printed in JSON format
```

If I store that state file in S3 or some such, I can then reference the outputs of the main script by using the `terraform_remote_state` data provider.

```
data "terraform_remote_state" "base_networking" {
  backend = "s3"
  config {
    bucket = "${var.remote_state_bucket}"
    region = "${var.remote_state_region}"
    key = "${var.networking_remote_state_key}"
  }
}

resource "aws_instance" "my_instance" {
  subnets = "${data.terraform_remote_state.base_networking.vpc_id}"
}
```

Is it possible to access the module outputs that are present in the state file as well? I'm looking for something like `"${data.terraform_remote_state.base_networking.module.<module_name>.<output>}"` or similar.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're asking for here. Can you provide an example of a Terraform file that would create an output that you want and how you would want to use it? It sounds like you just want to access the outputs of modules from the TF state file but your question already explains how to get at those so I guess I'm misunderstanding something.

Comment: Specifically, I have multiple terraform scripts where one is a "base" that gets applied before everything else. The others reference the state it produces. Inside that base script, I use modules modules and they have outputs that are referenced in the main script. I'd like to access the output of those modules in the later dependent scripts.

Comment: The answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39785310/77040) shows pretty much the set up I'm going for. I'd just like to achieve it without the extra boilerplate.

Answer (score 21):

Yes, you can access remote state outputs from your own modules. You just need to "propagate" the outputs.

E.g., let's say you have something like this, your `base_networking` infrastructure, which contains a module for creating your VPC, and you want that VPC ID to be accessible via remote state:

```
base_networking/
  main.tf
  outputs.tf
  vpc/
    main.tf
    outputs.tf
```

In `base_networking/main.tf` you create your VPC using your `base_networking/vpc` module:

```
module "vpc" {
  source = "./vpc"
  region = "${var.region}"
  name = "${var.vpc_name}"
  cidr = "${var.vpc_cidr}"
}
```

In `base_networking/vpc/outputs.tf` in your module you have an `id` output:

```
output "id" {
  value = "${aws_vpc.vpc.id}"
}
```

In `base_networking/outputs.tf` you also have a `vpc_id` output that propagates `module.vpc.id`:

```
output "vpc_id" {
  value = "${module.vpc.id}"
```

With that you can now access `vpc_id` using something like:

```
data "terraform_remote_state" "base_networking" {
  backend = "s3"
  config = {
    bucket = "${var.remote_state_bucket}"
    region = "${var.remote_state_region}"
    key = "${var.networking_remote_state_key}"
  }
}

[...]

vpc_id = "${data.terraform_remote_state.base_networking.vpc_id}"
```

Comment: Yes, I'm aware that you can set up outputs that reference the output of a module. I'm hoping that there would be some way to not need add that extra boilerplate. I'd like to be able to reference the module outputs specifically through `remote_state` in the same way as you can through the command line. The only thing pointing me toward thinking it would be possible is that you can do it in the CLI.

Comment: It's very well possible that this is the only way to achieve this. And, if so, then :(, but understandable.

Comment: As of Terraform 0.12 you need to reference `outputs` e.g. `data.terraform_remote_state.base_networking.outputs.vpc_id`. https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/terraform/d/remote_state.html

Comment: I get the error with this solution tf 12.24 Error: Unsupported block type on myfile.tf line 4, in data "terraform_remote_state" "base_networking":
   4:   config {. It does not recognize config block

Comment: Should be `config = {...`